# Old version of a component gets published instead of the newest

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, devexpress, publishing

**The problem**

I have taken over an ASP.net project recently, and I'm having some problems regarding publication of the web site. When I run the application from within Visual Studio it works perfectly both in Debug and Release mode. Whenever I want to publish some changes I've made, everything gets published except for one component. I have a separate namespace for all of the [DevExpress XtraReport](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/clsDevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReporttopic)s we use, and one of the reports seem to use an old version of the code when published. None of the changes I make to that specific report are visible after I publish.

My publish method is set to "File System".

**What I've tested/verified**

- As far as I can tell, the settings (such as build action, etc) are the
  same for all of the reports and the project file states that the file
  should be included.
- I have tried to delete `bin` and `obj` from the project directory
- I did a Clean and Rebuild on my solution
- I have published both in Debug and Release mode
- In the "Items to deploy" menu I have tried all options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the application was using a [ReportService](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument15665) to retrieve the report from the `App_Data` folder. As I did not overwrite this directory when publishing the solution, the `ReportService` were retrieving an old version of the `XtraReport`. To solve the problem, I simply deleted the file that the `ReportService` was looking for, forcing it to generate a report based on the new source.